# Android how to create menu drop down list view?

Tags: drop-down-menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoefF.jpg)

I find it too beautiful. please help. Thanks very much

Comment: Please see the picture that I attached

Answer (score 0):

You can use spinner [here is example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And resources:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: thanks for help. But I can not use spinner. Please look at the photo that I attached